# Counter example disproving: If $H = \{g^2 | g\in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups

I am trying to find a counter example to disprove the following statement:

> If $H = \{g^2 | g\in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $G$ is abelian.

I can't seem to find one. I suspect it should involve either matrices or permutations since neither commute in general and so these would be good candidates. Please can someone give a simple counter example or provide a hint.

Comment: Take $G$ finite of odd order.

Comment: I may have just found one. $G = S_2 = \{\epsilon, (1\ 2), (1\ 3), (2\ 3)\}$ seems to work because each element squared is $\epsilon$ and $(1\ 2)$ and $(1\ 3)$ do not commute.

Comment: Similarly, consider a nilpotent Lie group $G$. The exponential map $\exp: \mathfrak{g} \to G$ is surjective, and $\exp (tX) = \exp(tX/2)^2$.

Comment: @dable How is that set a group?

Comment: Whoops...It isn't

Comment: @Servaes could you provide an example of such a group

Comment: For another counterexample, consider the [quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group). the square of every element is either $1$ or $-1$, and these two elements form a subgroup of order $2$, but the quaternion group is non-abelian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k\in\Bbb{N}$ let $C_k:=\Bbb{Z}/k\Bbb{Z}$. The semidirect product $G:=C_7\rtimes C_3$ coming from the unique nontrivial homomorphism $C_3\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{Aut}(C_7)$ is non-abelian of order $3\times7=21$. Hence
$$H=\{g^2\mid g\in G\}=G,$$
so $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. The same argument works for any non-abelian group $G$ of odd order.

Note that the smallest non-abelian group $S_3$ is also a counterexample; in this case
$$H=\{g^2\mid g\in S_3\}=\langle(1\ 2\ 3)\rangle.$$

Comment: I'd have the smallest example first.

Answer (score 2):

In any symmetric group $S_n$, $\{\sigma^2\mid\sigma\in S_n\}$ is the `alternating group` $A_n$, and it even is a normal subgroup. Neither of them are abelian if $n\ge 4$.

Comment: This is another nice example, thanks.